# Expression similar to "I went past some point"

Tags: word-request, expressions

Consider these sentences:

> I was traveling by bus the other day, and I was a little distracted at the time, so I failed to notice when my stop came. I realized it 20 minutes later and by then bus had travelled 5 miles.

Is there a word or an expression to describe going past your destination because of some negligence or being absent-minded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the expression *I missed my stop.*

However, there are some other grammatical problems and unnatural expressions in your text. I would revise your text this way:

> I was traveling by bus the other day, and was a little distracted so I missed my stop. I didn't realize it until twenty minutes later, by which time the bus had gone five miles past where I wanted to get off.

In British and Canadian English, the present participle for *travel* is spelled *travelling*.

Comment: Thanks Shawn! I really appreciate you help, Could you please point out what was the unnatural part of the expression?

Comment: @Batman, (1) "travel(l)ing by bus" does not need an article; if you are explaining which mode of transportation you used, no article is required.  (2) "day, I was" is a comma splice, so I deleted the 2nd subject.  (3) "at that time" is unnecessary, because we know which time you are talking about.  (4) "didn't realize it" is better than "realized it" because of the introduction of my new phrase "I missed my stop," which is a positive statement.  (5) I changed "and by then" to "by which time" only because it reduces the number of 'and's' in your sentence. [See Part 2]

Comment: @Batman, (6) I changed "had travel(l)ed 5 minutes" to "had gone five miles past where I wanted to get off" because my rephrasing shows more clearly the distance travel(l)ed past your intended disembarkation point.  I also changed all of your numerical references to spelled-out words, as it is more acceptable for small numbers (less than 100, I think is the general rule) in written English.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: One to ten is spelled out. 11 to 99 is 'numbered' out.  Things get tricky after that for various reasons (words like 'million' and 'billion' look good in headlines, keyboards don't have a lemniscate (infinity) symbol etc)

Answer (score 2):

@Shawn's *missed the stop* is probably the most common way of putting it, but OP could also say

> He [**overshot** his station](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22overshot%20his%20station%22&oq=%22overshot%20his%20station%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.15706094&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (or [stop](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22overshot%20his%20stop%22&oq=%22overshot%20his%20stop%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.728&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

I can't see there's ever any difference in meaning between the two expressions. But for no reason I can put my finger on, if OP's *my stop* was replaced by a specific name (such as "Yourtown Bus Station") I think I'd prefer *overshot*. Maybe because it emphasises the fact of *excess distance travelled*, which you have to repeat in the opposite direction in order to get back to "Yourtown", where you want to end up.